# Traffic from OpenVZ host to container gets redirected to gateway

Tags: networking, openvz

An OpenVZ host (RHEL 6) is running Debian-based containers. The problem is that network traffic, instead of being routed to a relevant container (`10.10.104.1`) via `venet0` interface, gets routed to the host network's default gateway (`143.215.76.129`). At the same time, traffic to the 192.168.x.x network does not get redirected to the gateway. Relevant output below.

```
# traceroute 10.10.104.1
traceroute to 10.10.104.1 (10.10.104.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  143.215.76.129 (143.215.76.129)  1.349 ms  1.314 ms  1.280 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  *^C

# traceroute 192.168.104.32
traceroute to 192.168.104.32 (192.168.104.32), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.104.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 venet0
143.215.76.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth0
143.215.76.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth1
143.215.76.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         143.215.76.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `venet0` interface will always be routed through the host network, that is the [design of the `venet` network on OpenVZ](https://wiki.openvz.org/Virtual_network_device).

Since it seems you want to route traffic on the host to one of your containers, then you will need to make a proper virtual ethernet device which [OpenVZ refers to as `veth`](https://wiki.openvz.org/Virtual_Ethernet_device).  This gives your container's network interface a MAC address and other requirements for proper packet routing.

Comment: Much appreciate your prompt and helpful advice. However, based on my knowledge, the (overarching) system that we use is designed to utilize a `venet`-only configuration (not a `veth`-based one). I will get in touch with relevant people and keep you posted.